# Parse date format to timestamp in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have dates in the following format `9/28/21 8:08 AM` and want to parse to timestamp.  What is the best way to do this?

I have tried:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(colname, 'mm/dd/yy HH:MM AM')
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Can't parse '9/28/21 8:08 AM' as timestamp with format 'm/dd/yy HH:MM AM'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select try_to_timestamp_ntz('9/28/21 8:08 AM', 'MM/DD/YY HH12:MI AM');
```

You need 12 hour clock and MI for minutes.

Comment: this is perfect, thank you!